# R web scraping by class

Tags: r, web-scraping, finance, rvest, httr

I have a finance assignment for collecting the beta value for calculation, I am new in R, I would like to web scraping the beta value by package rvest or httr. However, output is character(0).

[image]

```
xpath:
//*[@id="StkList"]/ul/li[48]

library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

sym <- "1212"
url.3 < paste("http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/stocks/realtime/quote.php?code=",sym,sep="")

beta.value <- url.3 %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='StkList']/ul/li[48]")

output:
character(0)

desired output:
0.270
```

I tried not using xpath but, the html_nodes("div.value.highlight") but don't work as well.
Is anyone can help or advice ? Thank you.

Comment: Btw I couldn't see 0.27 in that page. Could you please let me know where it is?

Comment: @amrrs Beta +0.270. sorry for any inconvenience. ctrl+F and type beta that row

Comment: In fact I couldn't see Beta, Could you please update the screenshot?

Comment: @amrrs thanks for your comment. I uploaded the screenshot

Comment: Thanks @Peter but for some reason I couldn't even see this in the table. Maybe because i'm accessing from a different country?

Comment: What did u see then ?

Comment: I second amrrs here. I can neither find 0.27 nor 'beta'

Comment: Okay, after visiting your link, I clicked 'Detail Quote' and then I could see the values. However, the link did not change. It stayed the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They check referer before displaying the page, so you have to add some headers:

```
library(magrittr)
library(httr)
library(rvest)

httr::GET(
  url = "http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/stocks/realtime/quote.php?code=1212", 
  httr::add_headers(
    Host = "www.etnet.com.hk",
    Referer = "http://www.etnet.com.hk/www/eng/stocks/realtime/quote.php?code=1212"
  )
) -> res

res <- content(res, encoding="UTF-8")

html_node(res, xpath=".//li[contains(., 'Beta')]/following-sibling::li[1]") %>% 
  html_text()
## [1] "+0.270"
```

Comment: thanks, but i have a questions about the xpath, it's difference from the one that i inspect and copy xpath because I want to use it to copy Prev Close number and I did not success, would you mind guide me how to do it correctly ? thank you very much

Comment: thanks, I did sth like that html_node(res, xpath=".//td[contains(., 'Prev Close')]") %>% html_text()  got the "Prev Close11.380"